# How to add an action button for a specific row in gridview YII2 Advanced Template?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a `GridView` for a specific table in the database. This table has a status column which is `0 or 1`.

I want to add an Update action button in the `GridView` for the rows which are status column is 0 only to help admin update this.

I tried that but something is wrong:

```
 [
       'attribute' => 'Status',
       'format'    => 'raw',
        'value'    => function (\backend\models\Document $model) {
                         if ($model->Status == 0) {
                                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                                    'template' => '{Update}',
                                ];
                            } 
                        },
],
```

Comment: people are not just going to sit down and write examples and tutorials for you; thats what official examples and tutorials are for. you need to show how you have attempted to solve the problem and ask a more explicit question else your "please write my code for me" question will be ignored.

Comment: actually the system asked me to review new posts from people without any status on the site. so i was being nice by doing charity work by reviewing new questions by people with no status on the site. i was being nice by not voting down the question or moderating it as unacceptably low quality. i also gave feedback on how to improve the answer. you can ignore my advice of course; don't think that my grown up words and help are not being nice. i am trying to pass on my experience and be helpful. by all means ignore it. note your question is now "-2" and it would be "-3" if i was not being nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest was is to create extend from the ActionColumn Class and only render for your Status.

```
Class StatusActionColumn extends ActionColumn 
{
    public $testStatus = 0 

    protected function renderDataCellContent($model, $key, $index)
    {
      if ($model->Status == $this->testStatus) {
        return parent::renderDataCellContent($model, $key, $index);
      }
    }
 }
```

Or you add the code directly by setting the `buttons` parameter in the

```
 [
    'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
    'buttons' => [
        'update' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
            if ($model->Status == 0 ) {
                $options = [
                'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Update'),
                'aria-label' => Yii::t('yii', 'Update'),
                'data-pjax' => '0',
                ];
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', $url, $options);
            }
        },
    ],
],
```

I would do the 1st approach because on this way you can easily add also the view, update or other custom buttons.